# How to prove $\lim_{n\to{\infty}}\frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$

Tags: limits

How to prove $\lim_{n\to{\infty}}\frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$

My try:

I know that factorial function increases much more rapidly than exponential function but how to really prove it.

Comment: I think you want the limit at $\infty$. Consider what happens when $n>|x|$.

Comment: I think you can use the $n$-th power test to show that the series $\sum_n \frac{x^n}{n!} (=: e^x)$ converges. Then, its terms will of course go to zero :-)

Comment: Are you allowed to use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

Comment: @HoseynHeydari Never heard of it and not in course also.

Comment: @DavidMitra we expand the numerator as (x*x*x...n times) and denominator as (1*2*3*...*n). Now we segregate the fraction as (x*(x/2)*(x/3)*...(x/n)). As x/n will tend to 0 so the whole fraction will tend to 0. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $n_0 > |x|$. Then
$$\left|\frac{x^n}{n!}\right| = \frac {|x|}1\cdot\frac {|x|}2\dotsm\frac {|x|}{n_0}\dotsm\frac {|x|}n$$
For all $n \ge n_0$ we have $\frac {|x|}n \le \frac {|x|}{n_0} < 1$. That means
$$\left|\frac{x^n}{n!}\right| \le \frac{{|x|}^{n_0-1}}{(n_0-1)!} \cdot \left(\frac {|x|}{n_0}\right)^{n-n_0}$$
which is a geometric sequence which converges to zero since $\frac{|x|}{n_0} < 1$.

Comment: I had already corrected the mistake much before you gave the answer